# ROS2: ImportError: No module named genmsg

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I starting with *ROS2* which is currently in the alpha phase. While building the package `ros1_bridge` I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/ros1_bridge_generate_factories", line 11, in <module>
    from ros1_bridge import generate_cpp
  File "/home/ros/ros2_ws/src/ros2/ros1_bridge/ros1_bridge/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import genmsg
ImportError: No module named 'genmsg'
```

This is quite strange. On the same computer I build the same code without any problem. The only thing that changed: I have installed *ROS Kinetic*.

I found out in synaptic that I have now two different packages of `genmsg` installed: `python-genmsg` and `ros-kinetic-genmsg`. The first one comes as dependency of *ROS2* the second one with *ROS*. So may both are necessary. I think that is *Python*-stuff and I am not familiar with *Python*. What can I do to get it run again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens while dependencies installed for *ROS* and *ROS2* on the same
machine. Especially the package `python-genmsg` and `ros-kinetic-genmsg`.
`genmsg` can now found at these places:

1. /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
2. /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

This will bring Python run into trouble. In respect that `ros1_bridge` shall fit to *ROS Kinetic* the environment Python
variable `PYTHONPATH` will set to the *Kinetic* one:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Now restart the build and the build runs now...